# Is there a way to update conda and bioconductor packages in a yaml at once?

Tags: yaml, conda, snakemake

I've a .yaml file looking somewhat like the one below. Is there a way to update all of the packages at once without having to check everything manually (like looking what package is compatible with another version of a package)?

```
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - r-base =3.4.1
  - bioconductor-annotationdbi =1.40.0
  - bioconductor-biobase =2.38.0
  - bioconductor-biocgenerics =0.24.0
  - bioconductor-biocparallel =1.12.0

just much bigger like 30+ packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
conda activate myenv
conda update --all
conda env export > environment.yml
```

Or in one line (I haven't tested it):

```
conda env update --name myenv --file environment.yml
```

This does require you to have installed the environment already.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks once again :)